# How to split a string into 3 different variables in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of checkboxes with the names like the following:

```
q1_week1_monday
```

How can i split these strings into 3 different variables, for example

```
$quarter = q1;
$week = 1;
$day = monday;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `explode()` to split the string and the `list` construct to assign the parts to the variables. Afterwards, get rid of the week-prefix, using regexp.

```
list ($quarter, $week, $day) = explode("_", "q1_week1_monday")
$week = preg_replace("#week(\d+)#", "$1", $week);
```

Comment: The solution I was thinking of. Just enhance the `$week` to have only the number as expected.

Comment: Elegant solution Johannes. +1

Comment: @WojciechFrącz: Added extraction of the number.

Comment: Got this error: Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Corrected. Did too much Java in the last days ^^

Comment: `+1` -- this regex solution works better than mine :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split the string by a delimiter (`_`) and then use [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) to get the week number.

```
$str = 'q1_week1_monday';
$parts = explode('_', $str);
$quarter = $parts[0];
$week = filter_var($parts[1], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$day = $parts[2];
```

Using [`list()`](http://php.net/list) construct (a bit more neater):

```
list($quarter, $week, $day) = explode('_', $str);
$week = filter_var($week, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Note: This assumes the middle part of the string contains only one number.

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/61077)

Comment: You bet me by 6 secs :)

Comment: the substr() construct won'T work for week nubmers that have two digits.

Comment: @JohannesH.: It's already fixed. Not convinced it deserves a downvote anyway.

Comment: Looks better now :) And - I didn't downvote, I totally agree with you, not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **`explode()`** and access it as variables like this

```
$str="q1_week1_monday";
$str=explode('_',$str);
$quarter = $str[0];//q1
$week = intval($str[1]);//1
$day = $str[2];//monday
```

Comment: `$week` needs to be `1`, not `week1` :)